# Issues with my jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I have created a basic plugin for accordion. My code is in my accordion.js file, which I have included right after including jQuery library. There is no problem with the accordion with this code in accordion.js file.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.accordion = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        speed:300,
    }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        var $elm = $(this),
            s = settings.speed;
        $elm.on('click',function(e) {
            $('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(e){
                $elm.each(function() {
                    if(!$(e.target).is(this)) {
                        $($elm.attr('data-target')).slideUp(s); 
                        $(this).removeClass('active');
                    }
                });
            });
            $($elm.attr('data-target')).slideToggle(s);
            $elm.toggleClass('active');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
}}(jQuery)); $(".accordion-toggle").accordion();
```

But when I initiate this with speed option from my page, it occurs twice.

```
$(".accordion-toggle").accordion({ speed: 500, });
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your accordion.js file you have `$(".accordion-toggle").accordion();` can you remove that and try.

Comment: Yes, I know that will work. But Its a plugin - I have seen that normally plugins are initiated from the file itself.

Comment: You are initiating your plugin with class selector. Usually we use data attribute to initiate a plugin from within a plugin itself. I suggest you look in to more on creating plugins in jquery. It's not normal to initiate a plugin with class selector in plugin file itself.

Comment: Okay, so I will see more examples in developing plugin. Can you please suggest other resources than https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/ to learn basics thoroughly - with good explanation? and also - what can be done in this case?